# Safe way to include a NuGet private source in a Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget

I'm setting up a Docker container for my ASP.NET Core server and need to find a safe way for restoring NuGet packages before building and running the project.

I've managed to mount a drive containing a new NuGet.config file solely created for this purpose, as my team doesn't include the config file as a part of the Git repository, but it feels wrong.
As the official Docker image for .NET Core runtime/sdk doesn't include nuget as a part of the library, some have suggesting downloading a windows image just to run `nuget source add` but that seems terrible as well.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5050

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

#Config file needs to be in root of solution or in User/share
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.csproj"
```

Adding a private NuGet source should be achievable without downloading a 2GB windows image or copying an existing config file that includes the password.

Answer (score 1):

Have a `nuget.config` file that lists only the package sources, not credentials, that's commit in your repo with your source code.

Use [cross platform authentication providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/extensibility/nuget-cross-platform-authentication-plugin) to allow devs and CI machines to authenticate to your private feeds.

Answer (score 0):

set the nuget's source path is not good enough?

```
RUN dotnet restore -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -s https://my-local-private-nuget-source/nuget/nuget
```

Comment: Are you able to specify username and password for that particular package?

Comment: @Atli, oh.. not, I don't be able to.

sorry my fault, 
and thank you for point it to me